# Menu item not available in UI if user does not have sysadmin role

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, dynamics-ax-xpo

I have created a form and placed it on UI by using menuitem.

I imported the code in test environment. End user doesn't have sysadmin role. So he is not able to see the Form button on UI. When we give sysadmin it showing him the form UI button.

How can I achieve such that user can be able to see form UI button without giving him sysadmin role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set security for it. In AX 2012, users have access granted through the roles assigned to them, directly or by AD groups.

A role is a set of duties, a duty is a set of privileges, a privilege is a set of menu items. So your menu item has to be added to this. SysAdmin has no security tested. For other users, they can only access to elements granted to them. If an element is not handled by the security, it will not be visible.

A good starting point: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731787.aspx

Comment: Thanks. @geoffrey DELMEE

Answer (score 1):

The security development tool is also a good way to determine what security needs to be assigned and to what menu item. You probably already know since you created the form but sometimes it can be difficult to determine.

Info on the security development tool can be found here.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh859729.aspx